# Log4j 2 console output stop working

Tags: log4j2

I've been using log4j 2 (2.7) and it worked very well until I had to reinstall the IDE (Eclipse Neon J2EE edition). 
Now I only works loggingto a log file but not to the console.
This is my log4j2.xml file:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>

    <File name="log" fileName="target/test.log" append="true">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class{36} %L %M %msg%xEx%n"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>

    <Root level="TRACE">
        <AppenderRef ref="log" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

**The output to the log works perfectly**, as I said.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring `Root` only once.

**Example:**

```
<Loggers>
    <Root>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="error"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="log" level="trace"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sazzad 's answer: you can only have one root logger. I would suggest specifying a level on the root logger and override the level only on the AppenderRef that need it. So:

```
<Loggers>
  <Root level="trace">
    <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="error"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="log"/>
  </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Also, not sure if this was omitted just from the question or from the actual configuration file, but the configuration really should start with a `<Configuration>` and end with a `</Configuration>` element.

Comment: Apologies. Corrected now.